Material3.colorscheme acting wierd when trying to implement dynamic colors
Im trying to create an app that includes an appbar on the left. Im rewriting the code to make it more efficient and remember what i had written ages ago. I'm having trouble trying to use dynamic colors. The colours look a bit washed out and not exact.
When using Material3.colorscheme.primary for background and Material3.colorscheme.tertiary for the button selection
The image above shows the colours when i use
Composable
fun Appbar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onScreenSelected: (String) -> Unit // Add this parameter
) {
    var selectedScreen by remember { mutableStateOf("screen1") } // Track selected screen

    Surface(
        modifier = modifier.height(500.dp).width(200.dp),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary, // AppBar background color
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp),
    )

MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
and
fun AppBarButton(iconResId: Int, text: String, isSelected: Boolean, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = Modifier.width(180.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            containerColor = if (isSelected) MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary else Color.Transparent
        ),

I have my colours defined correctly in Color.kt

import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color


val PrimaryLightColor = Color(0xFF135897)
val selectedLight = Color(0xFF1b69b2)
val background = Color(0xFFFFFBFE)

and Theme.kt

//private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
//    primary = Purple80,
//    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
//    tertiary = Pink80
//)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = PrimaryLightColor,
    secondary = PrimaryLightColor,
    tertiary = selectedLight,
    background = background,

    /* Other default colors to override
    surface = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    onTertiary = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    onSurface = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    */
)

@Composable
fun KalanikethanCICTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> LightColorScheme //DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}

The problem does not occur when I reference the theme colours directly.
 color = PrimaryLightColor, // AppBar background color

and
containerColor = if (isSelected) selectedLight else Color.Transparent

Produce the correct outcome.
Expected Outcome
However then I cannot use a dynamic colourscheme as I am directly referencing the colours. I'm not sure what the issue is.
I've tried redifining the colours I've tried directly referencing them and I've tried using the exact hex codes. They all produce the correct outcome. Just when i use MaterialTheme.colorscheme.primary does it look washed out. I want to be able to have a defined dark theme for the app so it would be nice if i can get it to work.
